# Div size differes when viewport is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

take a look at this site www.naamdesigns.com
view this site with desktop and also with mobile. In mobile, the header div in blue does not fit the screen entirely, it covers only 50%.
why this problem occur?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you set *overflow-x: hidden;* on body tag? I guess on mobile  100% width is only the visible part, where the whole content doesn't fit, but just half of it.

Answer (score 0):

lets try to put this in your head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

#### Added :

this is my idea, i dont know it's would works. Lets make a container to wrap all yor contents.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" style="width:100%">
        <div id="your_header"style="width:100%"></div>
        <div id="your_body" style="width:100%"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: yes, this is already included. I think the problem lies with the header alone.